# Foreground Dispatch system Issue in Android NFC

Tags: android, nfc

I would like to make one particular NFC application among few other NFC application which should have the following capabilities
1. The application should be launched only when an NFC tag with a particular text(NDEF type) be scanned on the device. (It means my application should not be displayed if any other tags with text type is tapped )

1. While launching the application  the option for "Complete action using " and listing of all the NFC applications in the device should not be there

Here, I have implemented the foreground dispatch system, but it is only listing all the NFC applications with NDEF_DISCOVERED priority.

The code snippet for manifest file is as follows :

```
   <activity android:name=".NFCDiscovered" android:label="@string/app_name">
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>  
    </activity>


</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
```

Here NFCDiscovered.java takes care of reading a particular text type NFC tag with foreground dispatch system. The code snippet for this as :

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.nfcreader);
    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,new 
    Intent(this,getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);        
    IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    try {
        ndef.addDataType("text/plain");

    } catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    mFilters = new IntentFilter[] { ndef }; 

    //resolveIntent(getIntent());

}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView myText= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nfcTxt);
    super.onResume();        
    if (mAdapter != null) 
        mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, 
          mFilters,null);




}
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) { 
    NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())){
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if (rawMsgs != null) {
            msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
            }
        }

    }
    List<TextRecord> records = NdefMessageParser.parse(msgs[0]);
    String text = null;
    for(TextRecord local:records)
    {
         text = local.getText();
    }
    //myText.setText("text :"+msgs);



}
public void onPause() {        
    super.onPause();        
    if (mAdapter != null) mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);    
}
```

It would be great if anyone can tell me what i'm missing.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It isn't clear to me that you are actually scanning the tag with  your application ALREADY launched and in the foreground, since you say "The application should be launched only when an NFC tag with a particular text..."

Foreground dispatching only works when your application is in the foreground. If it IS in the foreground, then there is something wrong with either how you filter for the intent or what intent is actually started. Can you check logcat to see what intents are started when you scan the tag and paste them here?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the contents of the NFC tags and are using Android 4.0, consider appending an [Android Application Record](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html#aar) after the text message.

Answer (score 0):

three comments :

1. you create and initialize the IntentFilter object and do use it at all. maybe you should remove that code for clarity, since you already use the foreground dispatch mechanism in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
2. recommend to use a NFC reader application from Google Play to collect the information about the NFC tags you try to read or write. the application can give the technology list the tag supports and the memory capacity it has.
3. maybe you can start from the active reading mode first. below the code segment.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onResume(){

   super.onResume();

   // here to scan code.
   NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

   // disable foreground dispatch
   mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);

   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   //
   mNfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(this, this, NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A, null) };
   ```

then you can focus on NFC message itself instead of activity dispatching.